# Channels: How to handle large number of concurrent users using Redis channel layer as backend on windows server?

Tags: python, django, redis, windows-server-2008, django-channels

I have a consumer method, which runs every 15 seconds using a scheduler(`apscheduler` library). The purpose of this method is to send JSON data to all the users in a channel group.

```
def auto_update():
    group_name = 'auto_update'
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        group_name,
        {
            'type': 'auto_update',  # this is the name of my consumer method which return json data
        }
    )
```

I have deployed Django-channels on the daphne server(as API server) and the Apache server is to serve HTTP/HTTPS requests.

When concurrent users increase more than 50(approx value), the next users are not able to receive data.

> Getting 403 handshake error.

What is the best practice for this scenario? Here, I need to only send data to a large group(more than 350-460 concurrent users can go up to 1000).

**OS:** Windows Server 2008 R2

**RAM:** 32GB

**Edit-1:**

On this server, there are two daphne instances are running. One for this application and another is for the same kind of application which is also having 350 concurrent users.

**Daphne command:**(as windows service)

```
daphne.exe -e ssl:8081:privateKey=cert\\development.key:certKey=cert\\development.crt --ws-protocol "graphql-ws" --proxy-headers real_time_data.asgi:application
```

**Channel layer:**

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [('localhost', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

What can be the issue? I have read daphne can handle thousands of users easily.
Can someone help me in debugging to find the route cause?

**Edit-2:**

From a [doc](https://redislabs.com/ebook/appendix-a/a-3-installing-on-windows/a-3-1-drawbacks-of-redis-on-windows/) shared by @MatthausWoolard,

> A.3.1 **Drawbacks of Redis on Windows**
>
> Windows doesn’t support the fork
>   system call, which Redis uses in a variety of situations to dump its
>   database to disk. Without the ability to fork, Redis is unable to
>   perform some of its necessary database-saving methods without blocking
>   clients until the dump has completed.

Is there any other alternative for windows server other than Redis which is a good fit for production-level use cases? Or any workarounds?

Comment: Are you using `SyncConsumer`?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar No, I'm using `AsyncWebsocketConsumer`.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar But the above-given method `auto_update`, was not running `async` mode.

Comment: are you able to test running your server on Linux (even if its just docker container?)  asyncio python + twisted on windows has quite a few gotchas.

Comment: @MatthausWoolard Nope. There is no availability of Linux servers here :( . Is there a better way to achieve this on the windows server?

Comment: @shaikmoeed you are running redis on windows is that supported for production yet? https://redislabs.com/ebook/appendix-a/a-3-installing-on-windows/a-3-1-drawbacks-of-redis-on-windows/

Comment: @MatthausWoolard Thanks pointing. I have tried to find the alternative of Redis for windows. `Memurai` came as a result, but don't know how to configure it. And it is not open-source as well. Is there any other better alternative of Redis for windows server?

Comment: @shaikmoeed no, due to the nature of these types of databases, they struggle to run well on windows. There is unofficial support for Channels with RabbitMQ (AMQP 0.9) but that is also not great on Linux but possibly better than Redis.

Are you running bare metal or in a VM?
*  Bare metal: create a Linux VM.
*  in a VM switch it to Linux

If this is a matter of making a company be ok with Linux running on their system look for a distro provided by one of the big names they will trust (IBM own RedHat for example).

Comment: In addition due to the different networking stack twisted (the framework channels depends on) will struggle to handle 200 concurrent connections on windows. Large numbers of concurrent incoming connections tends to need very particular Linux kernel configurations.